# How to vectorize a for loop doing an element wise multiplication of n arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I want to get an array containing the element wise multiplication of n>2 arrays. Specifically, is there a way to vectorize the below example code (here n=3 but I will in general need to do this for n>=3) in numpy?

```py
p1=np.array([0.5,0.2,0.3])

p2=np.array([0.3,0.1,0.6])

p3=np.array([0.8,0.1,0.1])

p=np.zeros((p1.shape[0],p2.shape[0],p3.shape[0] ))
for i in range(p1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(p2.shape[0]):
        for k in range(p3.shape[0]):
           p[i,j,k] = p1[i]*p2[j]*p3[k]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a generic one for a generic number of input arrays using [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to make them outer-broadcastable against each other -

```
In [83]: A = [p1,p2,p3] # list of all input arrays

In [84]: np.multiply.reduce(np.ix_(*A))
Out[84]: 
array([[[0.12 , 0.015, 0.015],
        [0.04 , 0.005, 0.005],
        [0.24 , 0.03 , 0.03 ]],

       [[0.048, 0.006, 0.006],
        [0.016, 0.002, 0.002],
        [0.096, 0.012, 0.012]],

       [[0.072, 0.009, 0.009],
        [0.024, 0.003, 0.003],
        [0.144, 0.018, 0.018]]])
```

Comment: Thanks! That what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an [outer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) product. First perform an outer product of `p1` and `p2`, followed by the outer product with `p3`. The reshaping can be done as desired

```
prod = np.outer(np.outer(p1, p2), p3)

prod = prod.reshape((p1.shape[0],p2.shape[0],p3.shape[0] ))
```

EDIT: Generalised solution suggested by @Yann Vernier in the comments below

```
from functools import reduce
ps = [p1, p2, p3]
prod = reduce(np.outer, ps).reshape([p.shape[0] for p in ps])

# array([[[0.12 , 0.015, 0.015],
#         [0.04 , 0.005, 0.005],
#         [0.24 , 0.03 , 0.03 ]],

#        [[0.048, 0.006, 0.006],
#         [0.016, 0.002, 0.002],
#         [0.096, 0.012, 0.012]],

#        [[0.072, 0.009, 0.009],
#         [0.024, 0.003, 0.003],
#         [0.144, 0.018, 0.018]]])
```

Comment: He said he wants a general method to do it with `n` vectors, not just 3,

Comment: @dome: Oh, sorry I overlooked. Give me some time to make it more general

Comment: So generalize it? `prod = reduce(np.outer, ps).reshape([p.shape[0] for p in ps])`

Comment: @YannVernier: Thanks for the pointer. I acknowledged you and your comment in the answer. I hope you don't mind. If you do, feel free to comment and I will delete my answer

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that this is called outer product. I had no idea! I think my question in the title is more generic than the one my question is marked duplicate for. That question has "outer product" in the title. I'm sure that most people trying to solve a problem like mine would not have known that it is called outer product. Once you know, it is much easier to vectorize. Thanks!